# How to give modded armor to MCA villagers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

I'm playing a homemade modpack with Forge and I was wondering how to give my wife in Minecraft Comes Alive armor from the Super Hero Unlimited mod for her to put on. How do I do this?

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Exactly what mods are you using?  What have you tried so far?  Have you looked at the documentation for the mod?

Comment: What XD. im using MCA (minecraft comes alive) and superheroes unlimited. I havent tried anything cause super suits are exspensive and I don't know a secure way of doing it. and yes... it was useless....

Comment: So you haven't tried to to do it but you're asking how to do it?  I suggest trying it first and reporting what doesn't work before you come here.

Comment: I just did... i was right, she rejected the armor by gifting it too her. And from using google there is no other way (For 1.7.10) that i could find.

Answer (score 1):

Go into her inventory and equip the armor (even modded! As they use player models) at the most left inventory slots. Now if only we could equip them with weapons!

Comment: yep, but she might not recognise that its armour, its from a seperate mod. however i think she will because armour will be classified as armour. and dont forget, you must be married to manage her inventory. just drop it in.